# jQuery UI Tabs with 100% height has content and vertical scrollbars that are extended below the visible area

Tags: css, html, html-lists, overflow, jquery-ui-tabs

Have a strange problem (strange because I do not understand it)

Trying to use jQuery UI Tabs with 100% height and a vertical overflow scrollbar for the content.

This does not work - the scrollable area is bigger then the visible area resulting in the lower part of the scrollbar to be below the visible area. Looks like the scroll area is extended with the height of the list area.

The problem is only valid with 100% height (have testet this in different ways). As soon as I set a fixed height (in some way) the problem is gone???

Have after some test found out that the UI is not to blame and the problem is also valid with native list items.

My setup is this:

- I need to use all available space (complete iframe, div, window)
- I do not know the height of the top list.
- I need to use the remaining space for content with vertical overflow
- Will not use a script to modify the height (must be possible with CSS and HTML5 alone)

You can see a demonstration here:

http://jsfiddle.net/beasty/6cAat/10/

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Thank you
Benny

Comment: `height: 100%` means that the element is 100% of the height of its parent, not that it will take up 100% of the remaining space.

Comment: I know that setting some hight clear the problem.

But my setup is this:

I need to use all available space (complete iframe, div, window)
I do not know the height of the top list.
I need to use the remaining space for content with overflow-y

How do I do this?

Comment: The way I've done it is to `position: absolute` a container div with left, right and bottom set to zero and top either set to a fixed value (if there is a fixed header, for example) or a calculated value that would be recalculated on load, content change, window resize, etc.

Comment: Yes I know this is possibility with added JavaScript but can not understand that this simple setup is not directly possible with CSS and HTML5 alone

Answer (score 2):

The css property height: 100% has no effect on relatively positioned elements.

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 100%; border-style: solid; border-width:2px;">

    <div id="contenttab" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; overflow-y: auto;">

        Looong text

    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/6cAat/12/) a slightly better way to do this. You'll still have to determine the height of the list above the absolutely positioned div.

Comment: The height property actually does have an effect in this case since its only child is absolutely positioned; without the height declaration its height effectively becomes zero (unless the overflow property is used).

Comment: I know that setting some hight clear the problem.

But my setup is this:

I need to use all available space (complete iframe, div, window)
I do not know the height of the top list.
I need to use the remaining space for content with overflow-y

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the top-level `div` element has its overflow hidden.  Its child `div` element extends beyond the height of its parent because its height is 100%.  The browser calculates the height of the parent, which in this case is 643 pixels.  So the child is also 643 pixels, even though it has to share the visible space with the unordered list, which is 60 pixels in height.  Therefore, 60 pixels of the child `div` element is hidden from view.

As a solution, you could set the height of the `ul` to 10% and the child `div` to 90%. But be careful! You're using borders which aren't included in the height declaration, so you'll still lost a certain amount of the child div exactly equal to the number of pixels of border you're using.  Also, if the `ul` ever grows, its contents could be cut from view as well.  It's probably a better idea to not specify a height for the child `div` or the `ul` and instead allow the parent `div` to overflow-y.  Otherwise it kind of seems "frame-y".

Comment: I know that setting some hight clear the problem.

But my setup is this:

I need to use all available space (complete iframe, div, window)
I do not know the height of the top list.
I need to use the remaining space for content with overflow-y

How do I do this?

Comment: The borders are not needed in my real setup and you approch will also scroll the header list (do not like that)

Comment: You can remove the borders, but in the example the header list does not scroll.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to your suggestion to "allow the parent div to overflow-y".

Comment: Yes it works in your example as you have set a fixed hight (procentage) for the list and content. I simply do not understand why it is needed that way. Do I really need to calculate or know the size in advance. The height of the list will vary!

Comment: Frankly, I don't know the properties of the container element. How is it positioned? How can it grow on the page? Depending on those answers, you may not have to explicitly define a height. Can you provide an example of the entire page?

Comment: I need to use UI tabs on this page http://pcrypt.org to combine passwords and groups. Tabs will in the new layout be groups and everything will be in the same page compared to now where it is handled in 2 different pages. I do not know in advance how many groups/tabs the user create (variable). Below is the passwords relevant for the selected tab/group.